# "Cannot POST /api/graphql" with Vercel Apollo Server (Serverless)

Tags: graphql, typeorm, serverless, vercel, typegraphql

I am trying to setup a severless Apollo server with Vercel, TypeGraphQL & TypeORM (postgres).

To do so, I followed a few tutorials, and all of them suggest using the `apollo-server-micro` module as it allows to expose the `createHandler` method which is great for a serverless environment.

### Code

```js
// src/api/graphql.ts

import "reflect-metadata";
import { ApolloServer } from "apollo-server-micro";
import { buildSchema } from "type-graphql";
import { createConnection, getConnectionOptions } from "typeorm";

import path from "path";
import { config as configEnv } from "dotenv";
import dotEnvExpand from "dotenv-expand";

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") {
  const env = configEnv({ path: path.resolve(__dirname, "../../.env.local") });
  dotEnvExpand(env);
}

async function bootstrap() {
  const connectionOptions = await getConnectionOptions();
  const connection = await createConnection(connectionOptions);
  console.log(`✅ Connected to a ${connection.options.type} database`);

  const schema = await buildSchema({
    resolvers: [path.join(__dirname, "/resolvers/*.ts")],
  });

  const server = new ApolloServer({ schema });

  exports.handler = server.createHandler({ path: "/api/graphql" });
}

bootstrap();
```

```js
// src/index.tsx

/* relevant imports */
...

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: createHttpLink({ uri: "/api/graphql" }),
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <App />
    </ApolloProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

...
```

```js
/src/components/App/App.tsx

/* relevant imports */
...

export default function App(): JSX.Element {
  const initialState: IState = ...

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(...);

  // prevent re-rendering children when App re-renders
  const value = useMemo(() => ({ state, dispatch }), [state, dispatch]);

  // produced by CodeGen
  const { loading, error, data } = useUserDetailsQuery({
    variables: {
      publicKey: "some public key"
    }
  });

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <GlobalStyle />

      <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
        <NavMenu />
      </Suspense>

      {loading ? (
        <p>Loading ...</p>
      ) : error ? (
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error, null, 2)) // <========== where the error is observed
      ) : (
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data?.userDetails, null, 2))
      )}

      <AppContext.Provider value={value}>
        <Router>
          <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
            <Switch>
              <Redirect exact from="/" to="/wallet" />
              <Route path="/wallet" component={Wallet} />
              <Route path="/mine" component={Mine} />
              <Route path="/blockchain" component={Chain} />
              {/* <Redirect from="*" to="/wallet" /> */} // <====== Doesn't seem to be the cause
            </Switch>
          </Suspense>
        </Router>
      </AppContext.Provider>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

### Error

When I run `vercel dev`, I see the following

```js
{
  "graphQLErrors": [],
  "networkError": {
    "name": "ServerParseError",
    "response": {},
    "statusCode": 404,
    "bodyText": "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n<head>\n<meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n<title>Error</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n<pre>Cannot POST /api/graphql</pre>\n</body>\n</html>\n"
  },
  "message": "Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"
}
```

I also see: `POST http://localhost:3000/api/graphql 404 (Not Found)` at `createHttpLink.ts:145`

### Question

What am I missing here?
My database connection works fine as I checked it locally before trying with `vercel dev`.
I also added the env variables to vercel (production, preview, and development branches).

Comment: Could you move module.exports out of bootstrap function. What i would do is module.exports = bootstrap(); and return handler from bootstrap.

Comment: You would have to await it since it is a async function.

Comment: You cannot await outside of an async function though. I think I got it now. My folder structure was not correct. “api” should be at the root, mine was inside “src”.

Now just need to figure out how codegen works with serverless.